# Caller based Redirection ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can't believe that there is not a more elegant way to redirect from a ASP.NET MVC 3 controller action than this one. Is it the best?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** What I mean is that if the Action is called from different places I need to go back to the original place.

```
string baseUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
    string url = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();

    if (url.ToLower().Contains("store"))
       return Redirect(baseUrl);
    else
       return Redirect(url); 
}
```

Comment: depends on what the "store"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
return RedirectToAction("action");
```

if you want to redirect to an action in the same controller. If the action is in another controller, just add another parameter to the RedirectToAction, and it would look like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("action", "controller");
```

One more overload allows you to pass objects to another action:

```
return RedirectToAction("action", "controller", anObject);
```

And if you need to redirecto to a page outside your site:

```
return Redirect("http://www.google.com/");
```

Some references:
[Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

[RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29)

[RedirectToRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoroute%28v=vs.108%29)